# Coordinate system change and Jacobi matrix

Tags: real-analysis

Assume we want to change variables from the cartesian coordinates by the following transformation:

$ x=u,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace y=v $

Then Jacobi matrix of this transformation would be

$ \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{pmatrix} $

I cannot understand what is actually the transformation. As far as Im familier with, Jacobi matrix represent the differential of a function, that is, given a differentiable function, say, $ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $

Jacobi matrix of $ f $ in some point $ x $ where $ f $ is differentiable at, would be   $ \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f^{1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f^{1}}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial f^{2}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix} $

So what exactly plays the role of $ f $ in the changing of the coordinate systen $ x=u $ and $y=v $ ?

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are $u,v$ depending on $x,y$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net for example, consider the polar coordinates where $ x=r\cos\theta $ and $ y=r\sin\theta $

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what your precise question is...

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net for this example of coordinate system change $ x=r\cos\theta,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace y=r\sin\theta $, the Jacobi matrix representing this transformation would be $ \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & r\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix} $. As I said I dont understand what is exactly the function that the matrix represents its differential, because as far as Im familier with Jacobi matrix is just the representation of the differential in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n $

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get confused with notation when dealing with co-ordinate transformations. A co-ordinate transformation of $\mathbb R^2$ is by definition a differentiable map $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. This can be written, using $(x,y)$ to denote a point in $\mathbb R^2$, as $(x,y) \to (f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$, or alternatively we can denote the transformed co-ordinates as $(u,v)$ in which case $(x,y) \to (u(x,y),v(x,y))$.

Thinking about $f$ as the polar co-ordinate transformation, the transformation from cartesian $(x,y)$ to polar $(r,\theta)$ co-ordinates is given by $f(x,y) = (r,\theta)$ where $r$ and $\theta$ are functions of $x$ and $y$ defined as
$$ r(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
$$\theta(x,y) = arctan(y/x)$$
whereas the inverse transformation from polar to cartesian is given by $f^{-1}(r,\theta) = (x,y)$ where
$$x(r,\theta) = r \cos \theta$$
$$y(r,\theta) = r \sin \theta$$

Comment: And whats the role of Jacobi matrix here? are we using the jacobi matrix of $ f $ as a function of $ x,y $  or the Jacobi matrix of $ f^-1 $ as a functions of $u ,\theta $ ?

Comment: @FreeZe For a co-ordinate transformation to be well-defined, the Jacobean of the transformation (i.e. the determinant of the Jacobean matrix) has to be non-zero. This guarantees that the transformation works in both directions.